# invalid column name 'is memory optimized' when i try to create database diagram

Tags: sql-server

I tried to create a database diagram with my `MS SQL Server 2012`. However, it showed

> invalid column name 'is memory optimized'

Can someone help me to solve that issue?

Comment: are you running the SQL Server 2014 CTP1 Management Studio?  http://goo.gl/6QKpav

Answer (score 0):

Using names that have significance in the database system itself is always a terrible idea. The best you can do is change the name to something that is not reserverd. If you want to get an idea of the weird results you can get by using these sort of names check out this video:
http://sqlsentry.tv/the-dreaded-sp_-prefix/